# Logical formula with natural numbers

Tags: logic

How to write a formula using only quantifiers, variables, brackets, logical operators and $\in$, $\mathbb{N}$, $+$, $\cdot$, $=$, $\leq$ :
Among any three natural numbers exist pair of them such difference beetween them is nonnegative and even?

Is it possible to write it with only quantifiers, variables, brackets, logical conjunction and $\in$, $\mathbb{N}$, $+$, $=$?

Comment: Are you sure that neither negation nor disjunction is allowed?

Comment: If we had disjunction we could say $\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb N\,(\varphi(a,b)\lor\varphi(b,c)\lor\varphi(a,c))$ for some appropriate $\varphi$ ...

Comment: negations are allowed.

Comment: x @Jerry: In that case you can build disjunctions out of negation and conjunction, using De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}) (\exists x, y \in \{a, b, c\},\; x\neq y)(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}) \; x-y = 2n$

Comment: That doesn't satisfy the conditions -- there's a $\neq$ and negation is not allowed.

Comment: Then we wouldn't be able to specify that $a,b,c$ need to be natural numbers so it's not possible (also changed $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: On the other hand "such that" is part of how you pronounce $(\exists x) \varphi$ -- you don't need a separate symbol for it.

Comment: Sorry but i can't use ≠. how to write without it?

Comment: To get rid of the $\neq$ is there a way to directly say that there exists *distinct* $x,y \in \{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: Negation is allowed, forget it.

Comment: To be "precise", we have to rewrite $x−y=2n$ as $x=y+2n$.

Comment: And even so, this is not equivalent to the prose formulation. It is false for $a=b=c=5$, for example, where the difference between $a$ and $b$ **is** nonnegative and even.